# AS2 - On/Off button that adjusts visibility

Tags: button, if-statement, actionscript-2

I have a button that is a switcher on/off.
I have a movieclip that I want it to be visible true and visible false accordingly. If movieclip is visible true then make it visible false.
else if it's visible false make it visible true

This is my code:

```
on(release){
    if(_root.facebtns.eyelashes = _visible = true) {
        _root.facebtns.eyelashes._visible = false;
    } else if(_root.facebtns.eyelashes = _visible = false) {
        _root.facebtns.eyelashes._visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: So is this code not working? are you getting any errors reported?

Comment: No errors. It just works only once. Meaning I click once.. then it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
on(release){
    if(_root.facebtns.eyelashes._visible) {
        _root.facebtns.eyelashes._visible = false;
    } else {
        _root.facebtns.eyelashes._visible = true;
    }
}
```

This approach is working, if you target elements appropriately.

**use [is equal](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html) operator not an assignment**; the same code:

```
on(release){
    if(_root.facebtns.eyelashes._visible == true) {
        _root.facebtns.eyelashes._visible = false;
    } else if(_root.facebtns.eyelashes._visible == false){
        _root.facebtns.eyelashes._visible = true;
    }
}
```